# FFMpeg Closed Captions 608/708 Pass-through

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to encode MPEG TS file that is suitable for CableLabs parameters (without CableLabs embedded metadata).
Some of the input files contains CEA607 and CEA708 CC, which for some reason gets stripped during the encode.

I have searched for CC filters but I didn't find any filter that allows simple bypass.
`cc_stream_map` filter isn't good because I don't want to fill the CC data manually.

Example of the CC I need to pass-through:

CC Data

[image: IMG:]

Is it possible to create this kind of transcode using the FFMpeg?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've had hit or miss luck with getting EIA608 CC to survive transcoding. The short answer is that some decoders/encoders appear to kill it so you'll have to find the right combination. For me using "hwaccel nvdec -c:v mpeg2video" helps EIA608 survive the decode process and then using "-c:v h264_nvenc" to survive the encode process. Good luck if you are trying to use the HEVC encoder as I haven't found any combination that preserves EIA608 yet.